# Embed SAS Macro Results in SAS code

Tags: sas

I would like to include the results of a macro function call in a data step. I can do this indirectly, by first assigning the macro function output to a macro variable, and then using that macro variable within my function, but this seems inelegant.

```
data dataset_employee;
input name $ dept $;
  datalines;
  John Sales
  Mary Acctng
;
data dataset_employee;
input name $ dept $;
  datalines;
  John Sales
  Mary Acctng
;

data dataset_manager;
input name $ dept $;
  datalines;
  Will Sales
  Sue Acctng
;
```

It seems like SAS doesn't realize that the macro call is complete and I'm switching to regular SAS code.

```
 /*this works*/
%let var = %DO_OVER(VALUES=employee, PHRASE=dataset_?) dataset_manager; 
data combined1;
  set &var dataset_manager;
run;

/*this fails*/
data combined;
  set %DO_OVER(VALUES=employee manager, PHRASE=dataset_?); 
  dataset_manager;
run;

/*this works*/
data combined;
  set dataset_manager %DO_OVER(VALUES=employee manager, PHRASE=dataset_?); 
  ;
run;
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: I don't see the code/definition for %DO_OVER in your post? Looks like it was accidentally deleted?  Also the sentence between the 2 code blocks is currently truncated...

Comment: %DO_OVER is a macro mentioned here http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/040-31.pdf and can be downloaded here http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tight_Looping_with_Macro_Arrays, but I suspect the same issue will come up with calling other macro functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the failing attempt is due to an extra ; at the end of the macro invocation. Try removing it.

A macro call doesn't require a semicolon.
The first example works without a semicolon after the macro call (pay attention, you are using the dataset_manager dataset twice, in the %let and again in the set statement).

The third example would work even if you remove one of the two semicolons (one is required to end the set statement).

Comment: My understanding is that you need one semicolon after the macro function call, and another semicolon after the SAS statement. The final example (which works) has two semicolons together for that reason.

Comment: A macro call doesn't require a semicolon. Your third example would work even if you remove one on the two semicolons. The first example is working with no semicolon after the macro call (pay attention, you are using the dataset_manager dataset twice, in the %let and again in the set).

Comment: Remember, macros (and macro variables) are simply inserting text as if you'd typed it yourself.  Semicolons are only needed if they would otherwise be needed.  Most of the time they're harmless, but in some instances (like this one) they are not.